# Configure the message compiler (mc.exe) as a custom compiler step in VC++ 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can anyone list the specific and detailed steps to configure mc.exe (the message compiler) to compile a .mc file into a .rc file as a custom compiler step in VC++ 2010?
I am really lost on how to do this.

Answer (score 27):

Hans Passant almost had it right. Unfortunately, $(InputPath) and $(InputName) aren't defined in VS 2010. Instead, create your message file:

- Right click on your project->Add->New Item
- Select "Text File (.txt), but name it as a ".mc" file (like "messages.mc")
- Create a resource file (say, "resources.rc")
- Edit the resources file so it contains only one line:

> #include "messages.rc"

That file will be generated by the message compiler. Now add a custom build step to run the message compiler:

- Right-click on messages.mc and select Properties.
- In the Properties dialog set Configuration to "All Configurations".
- Under "Configuration Properties" click on "General".
- Ensure the "Excluded From Build" property is set to "No".
- Set the "Item Type" property to "Custom Build Tool" from the drop-down menu and click the "Apply" button so the "Custom Build Tool" property will appear.
- Click on "General" under the "Custom Build Tool" property.
- Set the "Command Line" property to:

  > mc %(FullPath)
- Set the Description property to something like "Compiling Messages..."
- Set Outputs property to:

  > %(Filename).rc;%(Filename).h;MSG0409.bin

The file MSG00409.bin is from having the following line in messages.mc:

LanguageNames = (English=0x409:MSG00409)

There can be a bin file for each language you add to messages.mc. The nice part of listing them in the output is that it will be deleted when the project is cleaned.

The only thing I'm not sure about is setting the "Execute Before" property to guarantee messages.rc is generated before resource.rc is compiled. I didn't have to set it, but if you find the resource compiler is trying to execute before the message compiler, then you'll have to set this property. It's disabled for the "messages.mc" file, but it can be set in the project's "Custom Build Step" property.

Comment: If your project already has a .rc file, you can simply add `1 11 "MSG00409.bin"` to it

Comment: whats the use of the .bin file should it be includes somehow?

Comment: if you have spaces in FullPath, then use mc "%(FullPath)"

Comment: there's a typo in there, it should have been MSG00409.bin in the dependencies, its missing a 0. I saw a project copying this exact info and then rebuilding all steps all the time because of it.

Comment: @LeonardoSantagada Maybe you mean this project https://github.com/tromgy/service-base

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the project, Add + New Item, select Text File, name it Blah.mc.  Enter or paste the definitions.  Right-click Blah.mc, Properties, Custom build step:

- Command line = mc $(InputPath)
- Outputs = $(InputName).rc

Edit your .rc file, add:

```
#include "Blah.rc"
```

Worked for me, ought to be close.

Comment: Prgress, but did you mean:   
 
Command line = mc $(InputName).mc  
Outputs = $(InputName).rc; $(InputName).h  
  
Regardless, this gives the error:  
mc : error : 0x2 trying to open file <.mc>.

Comment: OK, I am starting to think there is a bigger problem.  I make a TextFile.txt, then configured:  
Command line = echo "InputDir=" $(InputDir) "InputName=" $(InputName) >TextOut.txt  
Outputs = TextOut.txt  
  
TextOut.txt does not contain the $(xxx) macro expansions.  Does not look right.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing.  Make sure the filename extension is .mc, not .txt

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Macro names $(InputName), $(InputPath) are blank for me in the custom build step.  "mc.exe" fails, claiming no args.  In the above "echo" test, I try to echo the macro expensions to a file, but also come up blank there too.  Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 1):

In case `custom compiler` is not a requirement but more how to make it build .rc files from MSBuild.
The [WDK MessageCompiler task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh454227%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) offers this integration with MSBuild

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <MessageCompile Include="a.mc">
      <GenerateBaselineResource>true</GenerateBaselineResource>
      <BaselineResourcePath>c:\test\</BaselineResourcePath>
    </MessageCompile>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: So one has to install the WDK or this task is available more widely?

Comment: Seems like it only comes with WDK still

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2017 - then you can do following:

open up the .vcxproj file for your project, then add following lines inside the ItemDefinitionGroup :

```
<CustomBuildStep>
  <Command>mc "$(InputDir)\$(InputName).mc" -r "$(InputDir)\res" -h "$(InputDir)"</Command>
</CustomBuildStep>
```

This should generate 3 files .h, .rc, and .res - look in the designated build folder

Comment: you could also add a Pre-Build Event step:
just write following in Command Line for :

mc -A "LogMsgs.mc" -r ".\Res" -h "."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Custom Build Rule, you can do this

- Right click your project in Visual Studio -> Custom Build Rules
- Click "New Rule File" and fill out the fields, I use this rule file for MC.EXE

  ```
  <VisualStudioToolFile Name="Message Table Build Rule" Version="8.00">
    <Rules>
      <CustomBuildRule
        Name="Message Table Build Rule"
        DisplayName="Message Table Build Rule"
        CommandLine="[Location]\mc.exe [Unicode] [Verbose] [Inputs]"
        Outputs="Message Table Build Rule"
        FileExtensions="*.mc"
        ExecutionDescription="Message Table Build Rule"
         >
        <Properties>
          <BooleanProperty
            Name="Verbose"
            DisplayName="Verbose mode"
            Description="Foo."
            Switch="-v"
          />
          <BooleanProperty
            Name="Unicode"
            DisplayName="Unicode mode"
            Description="Bar."
            Switch="-u"
          />
          <StringProperty
            Name="Location"
            DisplayName="Location"
            Description="Baz."
            Switch="[value]"
            DefaultValue="C:\Bin\Psdk\Bin"
          />
        </Properties>
      </CustomBuildRule>
    </Rules>
  </VisualStudioToolFile>
  ```

Comment: Any chance you also know how to do this in Visual Studio 2017 ?

Answer (score -1):

Here I am giving steps to generate dll from .MC file (Message Compiler resource)

// Use the following commands in Visual Studio Developer command prompt to build this file:

1. mc -s MyResourceGenerator.mc
2. rc MyResourceGenerator.rc
3. link /DLL /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /NOENTRY /MACHINE:x86 MyResourceGenerator.Res