# Visual Studio 2015 - Does the message compiler (mc) exist?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Does `Visual Studio 2015` have a message compiler (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385638(v=vs.85).aspx)? I ask because I couldn't find any information on that.

I searched for `mc.exe` in the install directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0`, but couldn't find that file there.

Comment: It is an SDK tool so present in the SDK install directory.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\mc.exe on my machine.  There is an issue with the large number of SDK versions as of late, since v10.0.14393.0 I think, copy the file if necessary to keep msbuild happy.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing mc.exe. add eg, C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x86 to your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it exists, Please refer below path...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x64\mc.exe

Also, refer below link for the implementation.
[Configure the message compiler (mc.exe) as a custom compiler step in VC++ 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026855/configure-the-message-compiler-mc-exe-as-a-custom-compiler-step-in-vc-2010)